# RPG Map questions

Tags: leaflet

I have a map for my Pen and Paper RPG and I want to show it via Leaflet.

I put the Png-File throw a Tile- Making Script and was able to generate [this map](http://samaywiki.peulings.eu/Leaflet/samay_map.html).

I want to do the following things but don't know how:

- Place the equator on the actual equator of the map
- Putting bounds on the map, but only for the north-south-axis
- The scale calculates with the dimensions of the real earth and i want to give it the dimensions of my world
- I want my markers and polygons to repeat every 360°

I would appreciate any help,

Civer

Answer (score 0):

To get the equator you could use a polyline like

```
var latlngs = [
  [0, -180],
  [0, 180]
];
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

Not really sure what you mean by "putting bounds on the map". Are you saying you want to limit the user's ability to pan to areas outside of the map? Or are you talking about some sort of visual bounding line?

To do stuff with with different scales I'd suggest you look into how leaflet's Coordinate Reference System works (CRS). Take a look at this page: https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

It looks like you commented out some CRS stuff in your demo.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

With the equator i didn't mean i want to paint the line on the map. I mean I'am confused why 0° lng is where 90° north should be.

Yes I want to restrict the users movement. I can already do this with:

`map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(map.unproject(mapSW,map.getMaxZoom()), map.unproject(mapNE,map.getMaxZoom())));`

but than I restricted both on the lat- and the lng-axis but i only want to restrict the lng-axis.

I tried CRS.simple but that restricted the user in both ways like with the bonds.